# Definition of a structure issue

Tags: c, linux

I have declared a structure like below and when i am compiling i have a lots of errors like:

```
error: 'struct RW' has no member named 'num_writes'
error: 'struct RW' has no member named 'writer_cv'
error: 'struct RW' has no member named 'reader_cv'
error: 'struct RW' has no member named 'lock'
```

I thought that using a forward declaration will solve the problem, but it seems that it isn't. Or i am doing this wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct RW;
struct RW{
    volatile int num_reads_in_progress;
    volatile int num_writes;
    pthread_cond_t reader_cv;
    pthread_cond_t writer_cv;
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
};
char *buf;


   //Precondition: b->lock must be locked before this function is called
   void signal_next(struct RW *b){
        if(b->num_writes > 0){
            //if any writes are waiting wake one up
            pthread_cond_signal(&b->writer_cv);
        }
        else{
            //if are no writes pending, wake up all the readers
            pthread_cond_broadcast(&b->reader_cv);
        }
    }



  char *ts_read(struct RW *b){

    pthread_mutex_lock(&b->lock);
    while(b->num_writes > 0){
        //cond_wait unlocks the mutex, waits to be signaled, then re-acquires the mutex
        pthread_cond_wait(&b->reader_cv,&b->lock);
    }
    //By there b->num_writes must be 0
    b->num_reads_in_progress++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&b->lock);

    buf = read(b);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&b->lock);
    b->num_reads_in_progress--;
    signal_next(b);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&b->lock);
}

    void ts_write(struct RW *b) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&b->lock);
    b->num_writes++;

    if (b->num_writes > 1 || b->num_reads_in_progress > 0)
    {
        // cond_wait unlocks the mutex, waits to be signaled,
        // then re-acquires the mutex
        pthread_cond_wait(&b->writer_cv, &b->lock);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&b->lock);

    write(b, buf);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&b->lock);
    b->num_writes--;
    signal_next(b);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&b->lock);
}
   int main(){
   pthread_t white[3];
   pthread_t black[3];
   struct RW *rw ;
   rw = malloc(sizeof RW);
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      pthread_create(&white[i],NULL,&ts_read,&rw);
   }

   for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      pthread_create(&black[i],NULL,ts_write,&rw);
   }
   for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      pthread_join(white[i],NULL);
   }
   for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      pthread_join(black[i],NULL);
   }
   return 0;


}
```

Errors:

```
error: expected ':', ',', ';','}'  or '_attribute_'before 'num_writes'
In function 'signal_next':
error: 'struct RW' has no member named 'num_writes'
error: 'struct RW' has no member named 'writer_cv'
error: 'struct RW' has no member named 'reader_cv'
In function 'ts_read':
error: 'struct RW' has no member named 'num_writes'
error: 'struct RW' has no member named 'writer_cv'
error: 'struct RW' has no member named 'reader_cv'
error: 'struct RW' has no member named 'lock'
```

The same errors as in `ts_read` for the `ts_write` and `main`

Comment: The forward declaration changes nothing in this code snippet.

Comment: Making an immediate forward doesn't change anything. Make sure, that you are using proper RW structure. It would also help, if you've shown us places, where you use that struct. And also decide, whether it is C++ or C, that may be important.

Comment: Show mode code, especially the part of the code where the errors occur.

Comment: You have to show us *how* you use this structure, especially the code (with some surrounding context, like variable declarations) where you get these errors.

Comment: Is this [tag:c]? Then the declaration syntax is slightly wrong.

Comment: @g-makulik: The declaration syntax is correct in both C and C++, but objects of the type have to be declared differently depending on whether it is C or C++.

Comment: This is wrong `rw = malloc(sizeof RW);` should be either `rw = malloc(sizeof *rw);` or `rw = malloc(sizeof(struct RW));`. Doesn't seem like the cause of the errors above though.

Comment: Could you clarify which **line** the first error above applies to? Could you also confirm that there are no other errors before the first one listed. It's often not worth trying to solve errors after the first compiler error. So I would ignore all the 'no member named' errors and just fix the first error.

Comment: With complete code I see *another* potential problem, in that when you have allocated the structure you don't initialize it. That means all data in it will be indeterminate, and using any of the members will lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: resourceAccess.c:10: error: error: expected ':', ',', ';','}'  or '_attribute_'before 'num_writes'. This is the line : `volatile int num_writes;` from the struct RW definition

Comment: @laura I'm not sure, I never use `volatile` but as an experiment I'd try removing both uses of volatile, and see what difference (if any) that makes to the error messages.

Comment: @john: `volatile` won't cause errors like this. It is however useless as it does not provide the semantics @laura apparently expects from it.

Comment: @JanHudec I didn't think it would cause the erorrs, but since this is a mystery it's still worth removing to see what difference it makes.

Comment: Also, it's that first error that leads to the other errors. It's very common for C (and languages based on or coming from C) to have unrelated errors because some syntax error problem. Is the structure in the question an exact copy of the one in your real code? You don't (by mistake) have some Unicode space (or other hidden non-ASCII) character in the structure?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Unseen garbage in the source text is my best guess at the moment too. Plus of course the possibility that the code above is not exactly the same as the real code. A misspelling of volatile perhaps?

Comment: I made all the changes suggested by you. `struct RW *rw = NULL; rw = malloc(sizeof*rw)` .The errors are only connected with the structure.

Comment: @laura: The first error (and all the other are just effects of the first one) is either some unseen junk or spurious preprocessor definition. Since we have online compilers these days, can you please paste the sample to some (e.g. http://ideone.com/, but there are many other), so we can see the direct output of the compiler?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg you were right. i am using winscp to get the file on my computer and make the changes and yes, it was a syntax problem. Can you formulate an answer to can accept it? Thank you all!

Comment: now i am facing the real errors of my code: too few arguments of `read()` and `write()`

Comment: @laura Well read and write take three arguments each. I don't think you've mixed Joachim's problem either (I think you misunderstood it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code compiles without warnings on Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks with GCC 4.8.2, using the command line:

```
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -c ptc.c
```

The function declarations before the function definitions are necessary because of the compiler options used; I usually work around the problem by making the function static rather than repeating myself, but it depends on whether the functions will be needed in other files or not. If they will be needed elsewhere, then the declarations go in a header, of course.

I've marked the majority of the changes from the code in the question with `/* Fix */`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct RW;
struct RW
{
    volatile int num_reads_in_progress;
    volatile int num_writes;
    pthread_cond_t reader_cv;
    pthread_cond_t writer_cv;
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
};
char *buf;
void signal_next(struct RW *b);

// Precondition: b->lock must be locked before this function is called
void signal_next(struct RW *b)
{
    if (b->num_writes > 0)
    {
        // if any writes are waiting wake one up
        pthread_cond_signal(&b->writer_cv);
    }
    else
    {
        // if are no writes pending, wake up all the readers
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&b->reader_cv);
    }
}

extern char *xx_read(struct RW *); /* Fix */

void *ts_read(void *vb);
void *ts_read(void *vb) /* Fix */
{
    struct RW *b = vb; /* Fix */
    pthread_mutex_lock(&b->lock);
    while (b->num_writes > 0)
    {
        // cond_wait unlocks the mutex, waits to be signaled, then re-acquires the mutex
        pthread_cond_wait(&b->reader_cv, &b->lock);
    }
    // By there b->num_writes must be 0
    b->num_reads_in_progress++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&b->lock);

    buf = xx_read(b); /* Fix */

    pthread_mutex_lock(&b->lock);
    b->num_reads_in_progress--;
    signal_next(b);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&b->lock);
    return 0; /* Fix */
}

extern void xx_write(struct RW *, char *); /* Fix */
void *ts_write(void *vb);
void *ts_write(void *vb) /* Fix */
{
    struct RW *b = vb; /* Fix */
    pthread_mutex_lock(&b->lock);
    b->num_writes++;

    if (b->num_writes > 1 || b->num_reads_in_progress > 0)
    {
        // cond_wait unlocks the mutex, waits to be signaled,
        // then re-acquires the mutex
        pthread_cond_wait(&b->writer_cv, &b->lock);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&b->lock);

    xx_write(b, buf); /* Fix */
    pthread_mutex_lock(&b->lock);
    b->num_writes--;
    signal_next(b);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&b->lock);
    return 0; /* Fix */
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t white[3];
    pthread_t black[3];
    struct RW *rw;
    rw = malloc(sizeof(struct RW)); /* Fix */
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&white[i], NULL, &ts_read, &rw);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&black[i], NULL, ts_write, &rw);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(white[i], NULL);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(black[i], NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

<sup>*I've made this Community Wiki because there was a lot of effort by other people before me. I've not read all the comments, but they seem to cover much the same ground as the changes I've made.*</sup>